# django, admin template error Caught an exception while rendering: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'label'

Tags: python, django-models, django-admin, django-templates

good day guys!
in project, among others, have models:

```
class Category(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = False, null = False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Category %s" % self.name

    class Meta:
        db_table = "categories"
        managed = False


class Site(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank = False, null = False, db_column = "user_id")
    name = models.URLField(verify_exists = True, blank = False, null = False)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank = True, through = "CategorySites", verbose_name = "Category")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        db_table = "sites"
        managed = False



class CategorySites(models.Model):

    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, blank = False, null = False, db_column = "site_id")
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank = False, null = False, db_column = "category_id")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Relation between site %s and category %s" % (self.site.name, self.category.name)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "categories_sites"
        managed = False
```

so, as you see there is many-to-many relation. generally it work well - i can add and manage models through manage.py shell, or server-side functions.
I want to enable editing this type of relation on admin site, so, i've added admin model for Sites:

```
 class SiteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('id', 'name')
    list_filter = ('name', 'categories')

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {"fields": ("categories",)}),
    )

    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(SiteAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        else:
            return qs.filter(user = request.user)

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return True # So they can see the change list page
        if request.user.is_superuser or obj.user == request.user:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    has_delete_permission = has_change_permission
```

but when i'm going in admin->sites->Add site (or edit) django throws Caught an exception while rendering: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'label' .
how can if fix it?

Comment: What is the *actual* error - including the traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need to add undocumented `formfield_for_manytomany` method to your `SiteAdmin` class:

```
from django.contrib.admin import widgets

class SitebAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

   list_display = ('id', 'name')
   list_filter = ('name', 'categories')

   def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
      if db_field.name == 'categories':
         kwargs['widget'] = widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple(
              db_field.verbose_name, (db_field.name in self.filter_vertical))
      return super(SitebAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(
         db_field, request, **kwargs)

   fieldsets = (
       (None, {
            "fields": ("name", "categories",)
       }),
   )
```

to override default of not displaying multiple select widget for models with through option specified [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models).

Although this works I still think that this should not cause error in Django.

Comment: Lukasz, thanx for your answer - it really helps, but with category sites as inline, in admin interface it looks like one combobox with choices from categories, after saving with some category - new combobox appears and so on. i'd like to have a field, like, in users<->groups, or user<->permissions (ability to select few categories at one time, and assign all selected)

Comment: thanks again. but it works only in "one direction" i see the correct widget, with two columns, and ability to bulk add/delete categories, but on save it throws error, like: <-- Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model.  Use CategorySites's Manager instead. --> and he is totally right - i'm using intermediary table :), any chance to override this behavior (handle category saving function by myself)?

Comment: You're right. It looks like there's no easy solution to this problem. Many to many associations with `through` models are not supported as well as one would imagine. I don't know what requirement forces you to choose `through` solution, but maybe there's better way (better suited for Django) to handle that.